Adjust enumitem labelwidth dynamically to match widest label
I'm trying to typeset a set of ingredient lists using enumitem where I have ingredient amounts as labels and ingredients as the items. I would like each list to have labelindent=10pt and a labelsep=3pt, while having the labelwidth match the width of the widest given label. What I have so far is
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc}

\newlength\widestlabel
\setlength\widestlabel{20pt}

\newlist{ingr}{description}{1}
\setlist[ingr]{
    style=multiline,
    font=\normalfont,
    labelindent=10pt,
    labelsep=3pt,
    align=right,
    leftmargin=\dimexpr13pt + \widestlabel\relax
}


\begin{document}

\fbox{
    \parbox{\linewidth/2}{
        \begin{ingr}
            \item[3] leeks
            \item Salt
            \item[2] tablespoons butter
            \item[3] potatoes
            \item Milk
        \end{ingr}
    }
}

\fbox{
    \parbox{\linewidth/2}{
        \begin{ingr}
            \item[3] leeks
            \item Salt
            \item[2--3] tablespoons butter
            \item[3] potatoes
            \item Milk
        \end{ingr}
    }
}

\end{document}

which produces

As you can see, the hardcoded 20pt for \widestlabel works fine for lists with small enough labels, but doesn't work when the labels are too big (as in the case of 2--3). What I'm looking for is a way to essentially calculate beforehand the value of \widestlabel so that I don't have to manually find the widest label and stick \settowidth\widestlabel{Whatever label I think will be longest} in my preamble.
For reference, I was trying to come up with something similar to egreg's answer in Count and use the number of items in advance

Why not just use a tabular?
